# Using Disqus with headless Wordpress setup?

Tags: comments, disqus, headless

Does anyone have any experience using Disqus with a headless WP setup? I am working on converting a standard WordPress blog to a headless front end, with the users using the standard WP back end in the normal way. The blog is currently managing comments with Disqus, which I would like to load on the new static front end.

I read the instructions for setting up the Universal Embed Code, and am pulling in the post id as the page.identifier.  In my actual code I am using the correct short name.  The request to Disqus in my Network tab looks correct, but comments don't seem to be loading. Curious if anyone else has solved this problem.

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = document.querySelector('link[rel="canonical"]').href || window.location.href;

    this.page.identifier = '{{postId}}';
};

(function() {  // REQUIRED CONFIGURATION VARIABLE: EDIT THE SHORTNAME BELOW
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

    // IMPORTANT: Replace EXAMPLE with your forum shortname!
    s.src = 'https://example.disqus.com/embed.js';

    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
```

Comment: If it's a headless WordPress install, then this question really pertains to whatever front-end you're using, and doesn't have anything to do with WordPress itself, so this probably isn't the best place to ask.You'd be better off asking at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: good point, thanks